# Too many recursive calls or too many cout?

Tags: c++

Prints specific sequence by given n. For example n=1: 1, n=2: 121, n=3,1213121, n=4: 121312141213121 and so on. But for n > 11 the program stops working after 3556 cout. I think the problem is too many cout or too many recursive calls, but im not sure how to fix it or even is that really the problem. Please let me know if u have any solutions. Thank you so much!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int findNumberByIndex(int index, int& number, int n) {
    if (index < 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (index == ((int)pow(2, number - 1) - 1)) {
        return number;
    }
    index -= (int)pow(2, number);

    findNumberByIndex(index, number, n);
}

int printSeq(int rowLen, int& index, int& number, int n, int& counter) {
    if (index == rowLen) {
        return 0;
    }

    int result = findNumberByIndex(index, number, n);

    if (result == 0) {
        number++;
    }
    else {
        cout << result;
        index++;
        number = 2;
    }

    printSeq(rowLen, index, number, n, ++counter);
}

int main()
{
    int n, index = 0, number = 2, seqLen = 1;
    cin >> n;

    int counter = 0;

    if (n < 0 || n >= 20) {
        return 0;
    }

    int rowLen = ((int)pow(2, n - 1) + (int)pow(2, n - 1) - 1);
    printSeq(rowLen, index, number, n, counter);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Unrelated: You may want to replace all your `std::pow(2, ...);` operations with the much faster `inline unsigned pow2(unsigned y) {
    /* std::pow(2, y); */
    return 1U << y;
}`

Answer (score 1):

In the definition of `findNumberByIndex`, you forgot to

```
return findNumberByIndex(index, number, n);
```

In the definition of `printSeq`, you forgot to

```
return printSeq(rowLen, index, number, n, ++counter);
```

This leads to undefined behaviour.

Regarding your hypothesis

> I think the problem is too many cout or too many recursive calls

Unless specific concerns you can revoke the idea of "too many output". You could suffer from a too deep recursive call tree, but in your specific example your functions are tail-recusrive. With optimization correctly turned on, any decent compiler should optimize them.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielZhelyazkov You might have multiple bugs. Have you turned optim on?

Comment: @DanielZhelyazkov Also note that "doesn't work" is not an helpful description of what's happening.

Comment: I added return where was needed but still have the same problem.